# MySQL Performance by same type of integer but different spans of numbers

Tags: mysql, performance, integer

Let's say an `INT`

Is there any performance difference when searching through numbers between 1-100M and through numbers between 3.9B-4B, or just the same amount of bytes is involved without respect to their values?

As we know, when comparing for example `abcdef` and `abcXYZ`, they are scanned left-to-right, and a difference is not discovered until the 4th character. Maybe with other datatypes the case is the same.

Lets say an `INT`-type field has, for example, bytes `00 00 00 0F` compared to `00 00 AA 99`. Then, maybe, the difference should be found on the 3rd byte. Which would suggest that higher values are better for performance.

. . . Or maybe the whole work is done with a single 32-bit machine instruction? If so, then what happens with for example `BIGINT`?

And as a subquestion: Any difference when indexed or unindexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answers:  No and No.

Long answers:

`INT` (or `INT UNSIGNED) is always 4 bytes.  Comparing two`INTs` is probably done with a single 32-bit machine instruction.  Hence "1" and "4 billion"  are the same size, and can be operated on equally fast.

`VARCHAR(...)` (and `VARBINARY`) is a different situation.  When comparing 'abcdef' and 'abcXYZ', they are scanned left-to-right.  A difference is not discovered until the 4th character.  That is, comparing two strings takes a variable amount of time.  BUT...  This difference is relatively insignificant compared to all the other row-lookup, BTree-traversing, row-parsing, etc, etc that needs to happen.

The space taken for `VARCHAR` is, as the name implies, variable.  There is a 'length' of one or two bytes, followed by enough bytes to handle the characters given.

`FLOAT`, `DOUBLE`, `BIGINT`, `TINYINT`, etc are similar to `INT` in the above properties.  Fixed size (4, 8, 8, 1 bytes) and fixed comparison time.

`DECIMAL` and `CHAR` takes a fixed amount of space, but a variable amount of time to do a comparison.

- Do not worry about `INT` versus `VARCHAR`.
- Do not worry about cardinality *of the entire key*.  By this, I mean that `INDEX(city, state)` is no better than `INDEX(state, city)` when testing for both `city` and `state` with `=`.

But your question was about indexed versus unindexed.  There are two structures in the table:  The "Data" and, if present, the "Index".  They are separate.  The actual bits in the Data for the columns is unchanged if you add or drop an index.  The Index(es) have copy(copies) of come of the columns.

An index with a million rows will have a BTree of about 3 levels deep.  A trillion rows -- about 6 levels.  That is, the depth of the BTree grows very slowly compared to the number of rows.  So, again, you can normally ignore the size of a BTree.

As for the various sizes of `INT`...  I do not have the actual answer (without reading the code), but here are some thoughts...

- `SIGNED` may require a separate test for the sign bit.
- Before 64-bit machines were ubiquitous, I am rather sure that `BIGINT` was simulated via two 32-bit values.  This almost certainly required a 2-stage test, which might have been short-circuited.  Meanwhile, addition took two steps, and multiplication too several.  Possibly MySQL was implemented on a few 16-bit machines, so even `INT` had to be split up.
- I really doubt if `INT` is done a byte at a time; it would make more sense to extract the 4 bytes in common code, then perform a machine-level signed or unsigned comparison.
- Note that `DECIMAL` cannot be done the same as `INT` due to its variable-length nature.
- Will things become more 'atomic' in the future?  Possibly.  Let's go back in time to old implementations of floating point.  The last stage of most operations is to left shift the result to 'normalize' the representation.  Originally, this involved a loop to "left shift by 1 (or 2 or 3 (octal) or 4 (hex)) bits until the first is no longer zero".  Pretty quickly they invented 'barrel shifters', etc, that allowed this task to be done in a single machine cycle (or at least a fixed number of cycles).  Division remains a slow operation due to still needing a 'loop'.  Maybe some day, variable length `DECIMAL` can be done without looping?

Comment: "probably" was not was i was looking for ... However yes, it is probably as you say

Comment: @Krupp - The details of how `INTs` are compared is _definitely_ insignificant in the big picture.

Comment: Updated question. And thanks for reminding me, because at the time of writing the question, it seems i have forgotten my own suspicions . . . forgetful me.

Answer (score 0):

I think at a low enough level, an integer comparison will have to potentially check every bit in each number.  So, I'm not sure that there is a performance issue with integer size by itself.  With regard to an index (B-tree), the biggest issue for performance is the cardinality of the column.  If the column has only a few values and many rows, then the index won't help.  As the index grows, and more values get added to the B-tree, I suppose it might take longer and longer to traverse down the tree.  But this also would not necessarily have anything to do with how *large* the numbers are, but rather how many *values* are part of the index.